# Strip certain objects out of a flat file database

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a flat file database and I need to strip certain objects from it.

There are numerous blocks in the file but I am interested in 2 objects in the `OBJECT NickCore` block.

Example below:

```
OBJECT NickCore
DATA display SomeUser
DATA pass sha256:2b35341220119fad48762e4f843d1544354f8b196cf09bf1b4ea39f9a31be063:5ff60fae76026907102419460aae83aa74daf374048940b612ef83460043b565
DATA email removed@removed.com
DATA language
DATA access SomeUsero@*.5A5E5CBA.81D21A52.IP
DATA memomax 20
DATA MEMO_SIGNON 1
DATA MEMO_RECEIVE 1
DATA HIDE_EMAIL 1
DATA HIDE_MASK 1
DATA NS_PRIVATE 1
DATA AUTOOP 1
DATA KILLPROTECT 1
DATA NS_SECURE 1
END
```

I want to strip the `DATA display` and `DATA pass` out of every `OBJECT NickCore` block in the file.

Desired output would be just comma separated:

`SomeUser,sha256:2b35341220119fad48762e4f843d1544354f8b196cf09bf1b4ea39f9a31be063:5ff60fae76026907102419460aae83aa74daf374048940b612ef83460043b565`

What should I use to do this?

Comment: awk seems like it would do the job

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/^OBJECT NickCore/,/^END/{s/^DATA display //;Ta;h;:a;s/DATA pass //;Tb;H;g;s/\n/,/p;:b}' file
```

---

See: `man sed`

Answer (score 0):

perl 1-liner:

```
perl -lne '$u=$1 if(/^DATA display (\S+)/);print "$u,$1" if(/^DATA pass (\S+)/)' filename
```